# What does $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(A)$ imply?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose now I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ which are of size $m\times n$ and $n\times l$ respectively. For simplicity, assume $n<m<l$.

Assume that I have $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(A) \ne \text{rank}(B)$. Then **can I conclude that the matrix $B$ will have full row rank $n$**?

I know there is a **special case that when $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(B)$**, for example the simplest case that the matrices are zero matrices, then the conclusion is not correct. **So I would exclude this case. I am wondering that if I exclude the special case, is the conclusion above correct?**

Comment: $A$ and $B$ could both be matrices with a $1$ in the top left corner and zero everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the conditions, I want to write it as $\text{rank}(A)\ne \text{rank}(B)$. But I wrote it as $\text{rank}(A)\ne 0$.

Comment: *"The can I conclude that the matrix B will have full row rank n?"*  No. An immediate and obvious counter example let A be the zero matrix and B be an all zero matrix except a single component is 1. More generally consider a simple blocked structure $A = \begin{bmatrix}I_r & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$  and $B = \begin{bmatrix}I_k & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$  where $k \gt r$, so $\text{rank}(AB) = r =\text{rank}(A)$.  In general $\text{rank}(AB) \leq \text{rank}(A)$.  You should investigate why, and what the equality conditions are.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know that if $B$ is nonsingular, we will have $rank(AB) = rank(A)$. I am now thinking about under what condition the inverse of the statement will be true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It implies $rank(B)$ is at least $rank(A)$. Since the rank of the matrix is the dimension of its image, then $\dim A(B(\mathbb{R}^\ell)) \leq \dim B(\mathbb{R}^\ell)$, hence $rank(AB) \leq rank(B)$.

As noted in the comments, you *cannot* deduce that $B$ is full rank.

Consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Hence $AB = A$, in particular $Rank(AB) = Rank(A)$. But $Rank(B) = 2 <3$.

Edit, another example:

For some reason, we want to consider $A$ $m \times n$ and $B$ $n \times \ell$ will $n < m < \ell$.

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $A$ is rank 0, $AB$ rank 0, $B$ rank 1 < 2.

Comment: I have excluded the case that was mentioned in the comments above. I want to know if the conclusion is true if the case is excluded.

Comment: Gave an example in edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I assumed that $B$ is of size $n\times l$ with $n<l$. If one more zero column is added into $B$. The answer will be better.

Comment: Now does the example satisfy the constraints?